# How do I put a number on my Google Chrome extension?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Google Chrome Extension Numbers on the Icon](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5759130/google-chrome-extension-numbers-on-the-icon)

So I'm developing a chrome extension and I would like to put a number on the icon. I'm assuming this is done through the canvas element but I can't find any examples. Anyone have an example they want to share?

Comment: I have answered a similar question. You may look [there](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5759130/google-chrome-extension-numbers-on-the-icon/12237406#12237406 "A similar soultion."). If still any doubt you can ask further questions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The number is called a "badge", and you can use up to four characters: http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/browserAction.html

Call `setBadgeText()` to change it.

Comment: Are you serious? Ha ha thanks!