# Google Chrome Extension Numbers on the Icon

Tags: icons, google-chrome-extension

I've been experimenting with a Chrome Extension, and I want to make one similar to my Google Voice Extension where the icon shows a little blue "1" next to the icon when I receive an event, Is this a whole separate icon? and then they just use the "setIcon" method? Like this

```
chrome.browserAction.setIcon({path:"icon.png"});
```

Here's a visual example of how it looks:
[image]

The gmail one seems to go all the up to 500! They can't have an icon for each number, or do they?? Is there something I can use thats made to do this stuff? I already have my icon, if I have to make a unique one I may just make like 10 and then have a "10+" icon. I am connecting it to an API which could have a lot of events.

Has anybody had this issue? How did they get around it?

Any advice or suggestions would help!

Thanks!

Comment: Doing something similar Doug... pretty funny landing on your question. Hope all is well! - Edu

Answer (score 119, accepted):

#### Manifest v3 update Mar 2021

According to the new Manifest V3, the APIs have been changed. According to the document:

> In Manifest V3 the chrome.browserAction and chrome.pageAction APIs are consolidated into a single chrome.action API.

So, your code for adhering to the new API shall be:

```
chrome.action.setBadgeText({text: "10+"}); // We have 10+ unread items.
```

#### Original answer

You can set a [badge](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/reference/browserAction/#badge) on your browser action with [`setBadgeText`](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/reference/browserAction/#method-setBadgeText):

```
chrome.browserAction.setBadgeText({text: "10+"}); // We have 10+ unread items.
```

Note that if the text you pass is longer than 4 characters, it will be truncated to the first 4 characters.

Comment: It seems also to accept strings longer than 4 characters. I have tried a time in the format like "**11:30**", and it is shown as a whole in the badge.

Comment: As @j0k mentioned, the change need to be in 'background.js'

Answer (score 37):

First you will have to do a few things. You need to have a background page on where you have to put the code for showing the BadgeText. And second you will have to register your background script file in the `manifest.json` file.

You have to make a `background.js` file or any other *.js file.
Then in the `background.js` file You have to write this code.

```
chrome.browserAction.setBadgeBackgroundColor({ color: [255, 0, 0, 255] });
chrome.browserAction.setBadgeText({text: 'your text'});
```

After that save it to the same folder as of your extension.
Then edit your `manifest.json` file  and enter this code at the end

```
,
"background":
{
  "scripts":["background.js"]
}
```

Now when you reload the extension you will see the word `your` as badge text because only four characters will be displayed in that small area. However it is not a hard and fast rule that the text string will be truncated to four characters, it's just that as many characters can fit in it will be displayed. I needed five characters and I got lucky that two of them were `i` and they do not take much space and all of the five characters got displayed. If you wanna try I was trying to display `Nidhi`.

Comment: it's also necessary to have ```"browser_action": {}``` in the manifest otherwise chrome.browserAction will remain ```undefined```

Answer (score 0):

MV3 combines the API's USE

```
chrome.action.setBadgeBackgroundColor
```

Manifest only needs

```
"action":{

}
```